# Is it possible to export only specific content types?

Tags: importing-exporting, nodes

While I was working on the theme update on my test server, original website got quite a lot of updates. But I can't just re-import the whole database, since I've got some new blocks and views here now. Can I somehow export only specific content types and import only them?

Any handy feature in Drupal itself, or maybe module? It should be a wide-spread requirement, since Drupal is such content oriented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [Node export module](http://drupal.org/project/node_export).  From the project page:

> This module allows users to export nodes and then import it into
>   another Drupal installation, or on the same site. The idea is similar
>   to the way you export/import Views or Content Types.